# 'Detection' tab never loads and gets stuck. Object detection uisng OpenCV & ESP32-CAM

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, user-interface, concurrent.futures

I'm using OpenCV to work with my ESP32-CAM in python in order to detect objects. However, upon running the code, only the 'live transmission' tab shows live footage of the camera, and the 'detection' tab in which the detected objects should be shown never loads and eventually stops responding.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
import concurrent.futures
 
url='http://192.168.137.237/cam-hi.jpg'
im=None
 
def run1():
    cv2.namedWindow("live transmission", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    while True:
        img_resp=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        imgnp=np.array(bytearray(img_resp.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
        im = cv2.imdecode(imgnp,-1)
 
        cv2.imshow('live transmission',im)
        key=cv2.waitKey(5)
        if key==ord('q'):
            break
            
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        
def run2():
    cv2.namedWindow("detection", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    while True:
        img_resp=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        imgnp=np.array(bytearray(img_resp.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
        im = cv2.imdecode(imgnp,-1)
 
        bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
        im = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
 
        cv2.imshow('detection',im)
        key=cv2.waitKey(5)
        if key==ord('q'):
            break
            
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("started")
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executer:
            f1= executer.submit(run1)
            f2= executer.submit(run2)
```

I've done a couple of hit & trials, but achieved no further results.

Comment: I'm using VS Code to run the file. I can't see any errors as well, and the results of this code have been provided: https://imgur.com/a/Wfc5ful

Comment: You need update https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: @toyotaSupra I've checked and it seems like I've already got the latest version of requests.

Comment: you can't run this stuff in parallel. GUIs do not work like that. there must be a single loop containing waitKey()

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Take a closer look at the code. There are already waitKey() in the loops

Comment: I said _single_ loop. you have multiple event loops here.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Ah my apologies. So for that to happen, there has to be a single loop containing waitKey() correct? If you can, could you provide me with your own code so I can have a better understanding?